# C# SerialPort クラスを使用して RTS/CTS を手動で制御する方法

Tags: c#, シリアル通信

ご存じの方、ご教示頂きたくお願いいたします。

現在、C# で `SerialPort` クラスを使用してモデムテスターを開発しています。

`System.IO.Ports.Handshake.RequestToSend` を使用せずに RTS/CTS を手動で制御する方法はありますか?

データ送受信の流れは以下の通りです。

0. シリアルポートを開きます。
1. RTS を ON にします。
2. CTS の ON を待ちます。
3. CTS が ON になったら、バイトデータを送信します。
4. データ送信が完了したら RTS を OFF します。
5. 相手側からのデータ受信を待ちます。
6. 相手側からのデータを受信します。

上記 1. ～ 6. を繰り返します。

上記の 1. ～ 2. と 4. を実現するため `SerialPort` クラスのプロパティは

- `SerialPort.RtsEnable` → `true`: RTS ON, `false`: RTS OFF
- `SerialPort.CtsHolding` → `true`: CTS ON, `false`: CTS OFF

と考えています。

試しに、RTS信号の出力がCTS信号に入力されるようにRS232Cケーブルを配線してみました。
この RS232C ケーブルを使って以下のコードで検証しましたが、`SerialPort.CtsHolding` が `true` にならずタイムアウトしてしまいます。

`SerialPort.RtsEnable` を `true` に設定しても、RTS は ON(Hight) にはならないのでしょうか?
(Win32API を使用するしかないのでしょうか...)

```
public class SerialCommunicationTester : System.IDisposable
{
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort _serialPort = null;

    // 0. Open SerialPort.
    public bool Open(
        string portName,
        int baudRate,
        int dataBits,
        System.IO.Ports.Parity parity,
        System.IO.Ports.StopBits stopBits,
        int readTimeout,
        int writeTimeout,
    ) {
        _serialPort.PortName = portName;
        _serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
        _serialPort.DataBits = dataBits;
        _serialPort.Parity = parity;
        _serialPort.StopBits = stopBits;
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = readTimeout;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = writeTimeout;

        try {
            _serialPort.Open();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("SerialPort#Open Failed...{0}", ex);
        }

        return _serialPort.IsOpen;
    }

    // 1. Set to RTS "High" and 2. Wait for CTS to go "High".
    public bool RtsCtsFlowCtrl(uint timeout) {

        if (!_serialPort.IsOpen) return false;

        bool result = true;
        // 1. Set to RTS "High"
        _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        // 2. Wait for CTS to go "High".
        while (true) {
            Thread.Sleep(0);
            if (_serialPort.CtsHolding) break;
            if (0 < timeout && timeout <= sw.ElapsedMilliseconds) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        return result;
    }

    // 4. Set to RTS "Low"
    public void RtsOff() {
        if (_serialPort.IsOpen) _serialPort.RtsEnable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: RTSやCTSが変わったかどうかを実際にラインモニタとか接続相手側のプログラム等で確認していますか？ 提示したプログラムが思うように動かないというだけで判断していませんか？ あと`RtsCtsFlowCtrl()`の中に組み込まれた形では無く、`RtsOff()`のように単独で制御したり状態を読み取った場合にはどうなったかといった情報も含めて確認し、追記してみてください。

Comment: `timeout`時間は何秒を指定して呼び出していますか？

Comment: 同じ運営の英語サイトであっても一応マルチポスト [C# How to manually control RTS/CTS using the SerialPort class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74572505/9014308)

Comment: @kunif 有難う御座います。また、マルチポストについてのご指摘の申し訳ございません。手元にラインモニタ等がなく、苦肉の策で RS232C ケーブルを改造して確認しております。本件についてですが、投稿した際は CTSHolding: false だったのですが、本日確認したところ、投稿したプログラムで CTSHolding: true を確認できました。明確な理由は不明ですが、推測ではデバッグ開始/停止、プログラムの他処理が影響して動作不安定となっていた可能性があります。

Comment: @sayuri 有難う御座います。タイムアウトは 5 秒 (5000) を指定しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NETのソースコードを読む限り、期待通りの動作をしています。つまり、

[`SerialPort.RtsEnable`プロパティは最終的に](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialStream.Windows.cs#L419)

```
EscapeCommFunction(_handle, <SerialPort.RtsEnableの値> ? SETRTS : CLRRTS);
```

が呼ばれますし、[`SerialPort.CtsHolding`プロパティ](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialStream.Windows.cs#L501-L511)は

```
<GetCommModemStatus()の結果> & MS_CTS_ON
```

を指しています。

---

> SerialPort.CtsHolding が true にならずタイムアウトしてしまいます。

は原因が別のところにあるかもしれません。例えば、タイムアウトを **1秒** に設定したが、

> ```
> if (0 < timeout && timeout <= sw.ElapsedMilliseconds) {
> ```

の比較により **1ミリ秒** でタイムアウト判定されてしまった、なども考えられます。

ちなみに.NETではこのような時間単位の誤りを防ぐために [`TimeSpan`型](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-7.0)が用意されています。 `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` や `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)` という記述が可能です。

Answer (score 0):

@kunif 様、@sayuri 様
お忙しいところコメント、および、回答を頂き有難う御座います。

本日、投稿時と同一状態で再度動作確認を行いましたところ、
RTS High → CTS Higt を確認できました。

何故、投稿時に期待した動作とならなかったのか明確な原因は不明ですが、
　・デバッグ開始/停止の繰り返しによる影響
　・他処理の不具合による影響
等々であったのではないかと推察されます。

Comment: 私の回答は役に立ちましたでしょうか？ そうであればプラス投票を。また解決につながったのであれば回答の承認をお願いします。